# Error while importing xlsx file uisng NPOI while it works for xls

Tags: c#, import, npoi

I am trying to import an excel file (xlsx) but it throws the following question :

Could not load file or assembly 'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib, Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But it works perfectly fine for xls with the same code.

```
  using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                    if 
   (FileExtension.ToLower().Equals(StringConstants.FILE_EXTENSION_XLS))
                    {
                        HSSFWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                        intCountSheets = HSSFWorkBook.NumberOfSheets;
                        EaRepos = DiagFunAnaClass.EaRepos;
                        objPackage = DiagFunAnaClass.objPackage;
                        plantCode = DiagFunAnaClass.plantCode;
                        buttonValidate.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else if 
    (FileExtension.ToLower().Equals(StringConstants.FILE_EXTENSION_XLSX))
                    {
                        XSSFWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

The error comes in the last line of the above code.

Comment: Why you have used `HSSFWorkbook` for first if condition and `XSSFWorkbook` for second condition?

Comment: What is the version of NPOI you are using?

Comment: I am using version 2.1. I have used Hssfworkbook for .xls and other one for the xlsx type of files

Comment: Tried version NPOI 2.1.3 but no exception is thrown.

Comment: Did you add the NPOI library to your project using Nuget? It seems like you added the NPOI dlls manually as references and your missing the ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll which is a dependency required to read .xlsx files.  If you add the NPOI package through Nuget Package Manager you will get all the dependency files required.

Answer (score 1):

I tried below code and it is not throwing any exception:

```
 string filename = @"D:\test.xlsx";
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                if (FileExtension.ToLower().Equals(".xls"))
                {
                    var HSSFWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                    int CountSheets = HSSFWorkBook.NumberOfSheets;
                }
                else if (FileExtension.ToLower().Equals(".xlsx"))
                {
                    var XSSFWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                }
            }
```

I think there may be two reasons for the error you encounter:

1. The file you are trying to access is open. You should close the file from all the editors and try again.
2. The version of NPOI that I am using is 2.3.0. You may be using older version.

Comment: The code I provided is working fine at my end. May be it is hardware related issue.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be correct and I also tried the Manprit's code. It is working correctly in my version 2.2.1. Sometime in NPOI functionality doesn't work even you are following everything as per documentation. Last thing I can suggest you is try typecasting the *filestream* type for XSSF  with *Stream* type like below

```
var XSSFWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook((Stream)file);
```

FileStream is derived from Stream class